# PostgreSQL database queries queue mechanizm (PHP)

Tags: php, queue, postgresql-9.2

I got a PHP web application which Postgres database, which gets lots of queries pers second (300-600). Database server is not that efficient so I get lots queries timeouts.
Is there any mechanizm that would make a queries queue before running them on database? 
I see it as a proccess/deamon which takes i.e. 50 queries from queue, runs them on database, waits for all to finish and get next 50 queries, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any mechanism that would make a queries queue before running them on database

Yes - [PgBouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) in *transaction pooling mode* can queue up statements.

It's highly likely that you probably just need to tune your DB server and deal with poorly performing queries, though. Check out `pg_stat_statements`, `auto_explain`, `explain analyze`, etc. Read [the wiki article on connection counts](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) and [slow queries](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions).

If possible, fix your client application so it does fewer queries that each do more work - do *set operations*.

For writes (insert/update/delete) batch them into transactions, and if possible run fewer statements that do more work. In particular, don't loop over an SQL statement where possible.

If you must use lots of small writes, look at setting a `commit_delay` or (if you can accept the data loss window) setting `synchronous_commit = off` for less important writes.

If your queries are mostly reads, I strongly recommend introducing a mid-level cache like the Redis in-memory key/value store, or Memcached. Have your application manage this cache to avoid repeatedly fetching data that doesn't have to be perfectly fresh, or doesn't change super fast. You can use PostgreSQL's LISTEN and NOTIFY features to implement fine-grained cache invalidation.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I just found this:
http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/
Have anyone used it to queue queries to database? Is it good idea? Documentation is quite poor.

Comment: @ZiomZiomalski If you're looking for an actual queuing system, for message queues look at ZeroMQ, ActiveMQ, Celery, etc etc etc. Not so sure about task queues, I haven't needed to deal with them, but see http://queues.io/. Also, please read http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/database-as-queue-anti-pattern.html .

Comment: @ZiomZiomalski Also, consider posting a new question that's better framed: "Here's what my application does, here are the queries it runs, here's why it does this, here's the performance problem it causes, is there a better way?". Include PostgreSQL version, key parameters like `max_connections`, a description of the task your app is doing, how that task is triggered, what you do with the result, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. My server administrators looked at the problem, and they suggest it may be 'hardware' problem with I/O disk operations. Disks are connected with iSCSI protocol and it seems that bandwidth between them reaches its limit.
Nevertheless i'll try to implement messaging queue.